# can kafka consumers with same group.id consume different topics separately

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

We have multiple kafka consumers on different hosts.

```
Consumer-1 (on server-1) consumes data from Topic-1. 

Consumer-2 (on server-2) consumes data from Topic-2. 

The group.id of Consumer-1 and Consumer-2 are the same.
```

It's expected that Consumer-1 and Consumer-2 can run separately to process message from Topic-1 and Topic-2.

However, we found that sometimes when we reboot Consumer-2 (on server-2) it will try to fetch metadata about Topic-1 and failed finally. If we reboot it again, it may fetch metadata about Topic-2 and works as expected.

I'm confused and find out [this page](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/131337/can-i-use-same-consumer-group-id-for-two-different.html) , if it's correct, **the key for topic re-balance is like (topic:consumer_group_id)** , why it's not stable?

We are using kafka version 0.11.0.1.

Comment: Is this the error that you get when you say 'when we reboot Consumer-2 (on server-2) it will try to fetch metadata about Topic-1 and failed finally.' ?
"Error while fetching metadata with correlation id {} : {}" If not whats the error that you receive before it fails?

Comment: And as mentioned in the post having 2 different consumers subscribed to 2 different topics can have same group id.

Comment: @AkhilanandBenkalVenkanna Yes, the warning before it fails is like "Error while fetching metadata with correlation id {}", so I can get that it's try to fetch data from the unexpected topic.

Answer (score 0):

Use Manual partition assignment [`Consumer.assign`](https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#assign(java.util.Collection)) method instead of `subscribe`. With `assign`, you have more control over which topic-partition a consumer should read data from. You can also commit the offset in Kafka with the same `group.id`

NOTE: With `assign` mechanism, there won't be any rebalance mechanism happens within the group.

Comment: Yes, as you said, there will be no rebalance operation triggered when group membership or cluster and topic metadata change, actually, there are more than consumers to consume multiple partitions for each topic, if one of consumers crashed, messages sourced from the partition would not be processed automatically, so I don't think it's good for us.